# ScrollIntoView() Function Not Working In Chrome But Working In Other Browsers

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, browser

I am making a website, and have made JavaScript code to scroll an element into view, and the more times I press the button, the higher the ID of the element that gets scrolled into view should be. It works correctly on Edge and Firefox, but in Chrome, it is only working the first time, and after that it refuses to scroll, even though the ID of the element is increasing. I would be grateful if somebody could help me with this issue.

This is the JS code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const scroll_button = document.getElementById("scroll_button");
    var scrollnum = 4

    function scrollFunction() {
        console.log(scrollnum)
        const product = document.getElementById(scrollnum);
        // Scroll the element into view, with smooth behavior
        product.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth",
            block: "start"
        });
        scrollnum += 2
    }
    if (scroll_button) {
        scroll_button.addEventListener("click", scrollFunction);
    }
})
```

This is part of the HTML code:

```
<div class="col product_row">
<!-- <div class="product_row"> -->
<div class="col-md-4 mb-2" id="1">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="./admin_area/product_images/apple.webp" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Apple</h5>
            <p class="card-text">tasty</p>
            <a href="index.php?add_to_cart=4" class="btn btn-info">Add to basket</a>
            <a href="product_details.php?product_id=4" class="btn btn-secondary">View more</a>
            // <a href="#4" class="btn btn-secondary">Scroll</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 mb-2" id="2">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="./admin_area/product_images/AZZAM yacht.jpg" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">AZZAM</h5>
            <p class="card-text">big yacht</p>
            <a href="index.php?add_to_cart=5" class="btn btn-info">Add to basket</a>
            <a href="product_details.php?product_id=5" class="btn btn-secondary">View more</a>
            // <a href="#5" class="btn btn-secondary">Scroll</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 mb-2" id="3">
    <div class="card">
        <img src="./admin_area/product_images/Bugatti La Voiture Noire.jpg" class="card-img-top">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Bugatti La Voiture Noire</h5>
            <p class="card-text">nice car</p>
            <a href="index.php?add_to_cart=2" class="btn btn-info">Add to basket</a>
            <a href="product_details.php?product_id=2" class="btn btn-secondary">View more</a>
            // <a href="#6" class="btn btn-secondary">Scroll</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="scroll_button">Scroll</button>
```

I put console.log(scrollnum) in my code to see if scrollnum was updating. It was indeed updating in all web browsers I tested. I tried putting a setTimeout() function in place so that it waits before scrolling, but that had no effect and actually did not even work.

Comment: Change the `id` attribute with integer to `data-id` - the restriction of not using numbers for IDs does not apply. Then, rather than `getElementById` use `querySelector` with a parameter like `[data-id="${scrollnum}"]`

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know, neither IDs or classes should begin with a number.

Anyway, try logging product instead of scrollnum to make sure the element you're trying to scroll to is actually updating.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).